# .mask return raw numeric length without spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#value").mask("?9999 9999 9999 9999");
```

The max length of the #value in my html input is 16. In google chrome, even though appears that the masked value returns the space as part of the value in my console log (length of 19), it will accept this combination. However, in IE11 (because I have to make it work for IE11...), it gives me an error saying the value is more than 16 digits.

Any way to turn that off or a way to make so that the space is a group separator?

This is the plugin I am using: hhttp://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Comment: What's that `mask` function ? If you're using a library, please mention it.

Comment: I've added the link to the plugin